# Performing operations on a collection of string arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I am reading a file that contains rows like

```
pathName; additionalString; maybeSomeNumbers
```

I read it using

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileListFile);
var fileListEntries = from line in lines
                      where !line.StartsWith("#")
                      select line.Split(';').ToArray();
```

This works well so far. However I would like to change the drive letter in the `pathName`. I could convert `fileListEntries` to an array and loop across elements `[i][0]`, but is there a way that I could do this operation on the collection directly?

Comment: Is the drive always a letter?  Or can it be a network location like `\\computername`?

Comment: @EvanL: The String to replace is a drive letter, the string I replace it with may be something else. `String.Replace` combined with `Substring` should work fine here. However, I wonder how I can perform this operation on the hole list of entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the LINQ extension method syntax in order to be able to use code blocks `{ ... }` in the lambda expressions. If you do so, you have to include an explicit `return`-statement.

```
var fileListEntries = lines
    .Where(l => !l.StartsWith("#"))
    .Select(l => {
        string[] columns = l.Split(';');
        if (Path.IsPathRooted(column[0])) {
            string root = Path.GetPathRoot(columns[0]);
            columns[0] = Path.Combine(@"X:\", columns[0].Substring(root.Length));
        }
        return columns;
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for showing/explaining LINQ extension!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it inline with the LINQ.

`File.ReadAllLines()` returns a string array, so you should be able to perform `Replace()` on the `line` from the collection.

```
var replace = "The string to replace the drive letter";
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileListFile);
var fileListEntries = from line in lines
                      where !line.StartsWith("#")
                      select (line.Replace(line[0], replace).Split(';')).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just call a method in your select that modifies the text in the manner that you would like.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fileListEntries = from line in lines
                                  where !(line.StartsWith("#"))
                                  select ( ModifyString(line));

        }

        private static string[] ModifyString(string line)
        {
            string[] elements = line.Split(';');
            elements[0] = "modifiedString";
            return elements;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lines.Where(l => !l.StartsWith("#").
      Select(l => string.Concat(driveLetter, l.Substring(1))).
      Select(l => l.Split(';');
```